# Group Dataframe by day using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the form:

```
      user                    accuracy  latitude  longitude      timestamp
0   5573502c150000c10136e51b    29.942 -8.658122 -45.700106  1434127670836
1   5573502c150000c10136e51b    30.000 -8.658068 -45.700127  1434127730889
2   5573502c150000c10136e51b    30.000 -8.658068 -45.700127  1434127790911
3   5573502c150000c10136e51b    30.000 -8.658057 -45.700123  1434127858915
4   5573502c150000c10136e51b    39.000 -8.658072 -45.700108  1434127918948
5   5573502c150000c10136e51b    31.876 -8.658100 -45.700107  1434128021062
6   5573502c150000c10136e51b    30.048 -8.658116 -45.700140  1434128151467
7   5573502c150000c10136e51b    30.473 -8.658118 -45.700097  1434128277097
8   5573502c150000c10136e51b    55.500 -6.658087 -45.700138  1434140105618
9   5573502c150000c10136e51b    55.500 -6.658087 -45.700138  1434140165685
10  5573502c150000c10136e51b    30.000 -6.658057 -45.700130  1434140225898
11  5573502c150000c10136e51b    30.000 -6.658057 -45.700130  1434140285952
12  5573502c150000c10136e51b    30.000 -7.658084 -45.700113  1434140346166
13  5573502c150000c10136e51b    36.000 -7.658051 -45.700138  1434140406214
14  5573502c150000c10136e51b    36.000 -5.658051 -45.700138  1434140466240
15  5573502c150000c10136e51b    32.908 -5.658091 -45.700097  1434140526278
16  5573502c150000c10136e51b    32.908 -5.658091 -45.700097  1434140586325
17  5573502c150000c10136e51b    34.009 -5.658075 -45.700119  1434140646363
18  5573502c150000c10136e51b    30.000 -5.658058 -45.700118  1434140706409
19  5573502c150000c10136e51b    30.000 -5.658058 -45.700118  1434140766455
```

I want to group the Dataframe by day and then to append each day's records to a different list.

So fay I have:

```
DFList = [group[1] for group in df.groupby(df.index.day)]
print DFList
```

But I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'day'

Can anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: `df.index.day` ?? but the index is not of type datetime na.

Comment: Your DataFrame's `Index` is the default integer range index. You'll need to convert the `timestamp` column to a `DatetimeIndex` and go from there, with something like `df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `unit='ms'` first and then convert to [`Series.dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day.html):

```
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms').dt.day

dfs = [x for i, x in df.groupby('day')]
```

Or if need `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
dfs = [x for i, x in df.groupby(df.index.day)]
print (dfs)
```

If need same format of timestamp column:

```
day = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms').dt.day

dfs = [x for i, x in df.groupby(day)]
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. Can you provide the code how to add each day's records to a list?

Comment: @Antonis - What column need append to list?

Comment: I use the first block of code that you provided. I want to add all elements except the 'day'.

Comment: @Antonis - use second one `Or if need DatetimeIndex:` :)

Comment: @Antonis - also if need nested lists `dfs = [x.values.tolist() for i, x in df.groupby(df.index.day)]`

Comment: I want the timestamps in the form 1434127670836.Not 2015-06-11 21:20:21.378

Comment: Which part to you mean?

Comment: @Antonis - last paragraph.